# Query a PostgreSQL view created by SQLAcodegen

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, sql-view, sqlacodegen

I have a useful PostgreSQL view, generated by a JOIN query:

```
\d very_useful_view;
 View "public.very_useful_view"
   Column    |    Type     | Modifiers
-------------+-------------+-----------
 tree_id     | dom_treeid  |
 title       | text        |
 grass_id    | dom_grass   |
 name        | text        |
 street_uuid | uuid        |
```

The view was modeled by [SQLAcodegen](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sqlacodegen) to the following object:

```
t_very_useful_view = Table(
    'very_useful_view', metadata,
    Column('tree_id', String),
    Column('title', Text),
    Column('grass_id', Text),
    Column('name', Text),
    Column('street_uuid', UUID)
)
```

Normal query works as expected:

```
print session.query(t_very_useful_view).all()
```

However, filtering -

```
print session.query(t_very_useful_view).\
    filter(t_very_useful_view.tree_id == some_tree_id).\
    all()
```

Raises:

```
AttributeError: 'Table' object has no attribute 'tree_id'
```

**Any idea what am I missing with the view mapping?**

Answer (score 1):

The columns of a `Table` object [should be accessed with the `columns` property](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html?highlight=table#sqlalchemy.schema.Table.columns):

```
print session.query(t_very_useful_view).\
    filter(t_very_useful_view.columns.tree_id == some_tree_id).\
    all()
```

This contrasts with subclasses of `declarative_base()`, which expose columns as root-level object properties.